# Using VirtualBox on Win 10 to access XP

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, windows-10

I'm thinking about upgrading to Windows 10 from 7, but I've heard that some sites won't work under 10 due to privacy concerns.

If I use VirtualBox to "install" Win XP, will the sites I visit see me as using XP or 10?

Also, would the security holes in XP be an issue, or does Win 10 somehow prevent them from being exploited?

Comment: VirtualBox isn't really working in Windows 10 at the moment, but they're working on it. So I wouldn't rely on that. The host doesn't help with any security issues and I've yet to hear about sites that would stop working based on the OS.

Comment: Loaded up my XP VM on Virtual Box (I'm on Windows 7.)  Going to [What's My Browser](http://www.whatsmybrowser.org) from the VM shows IE6 on Windows XP.